# Inferred type arguments

Tags: scala, parameters, self-type, inferred-type

Why am I getting an error while compiling this snippet?

```
trait ID[R <: Record[R] with KeyedRecord[Long]] {

  this: R =>

  val idField = new LongField(this)
}
```

ERROR:

```
inferred type arguments [ID[R] with R] do not conform to class LongField's
type parameter bounds [OwnerType <: net.liftweb.record.Record[OwnerType]]
```

How can I fix this?

---

LongField definition:

```
class LongField[OwnerType <: Record[OwnerType]](rec: OwnerType)
  extends Field[Long, OwnerType] with MandatoryTypedField[Long] with LongTypedField {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert

```
val idField = new LongField(this)
```

to

```
val idField = new LongField[R](this)
```

If you do not specify the type `R`, then the LongField cannot check if the type is co-variant to `Record[OwnerType]` or not. Explicitly mentioning it should solve the purpose.

PS: I do not know the other class declaration to re-confirm, but the below declaration works:

```
case class Record[R]
class KeyedRecord[R] extends Record[R]
class LongField[OwnerType <: Record[OwnerType]](rec: OwnerType)
trait ID[R <: Record[R] with KeyedRecord[Long]] {
  this: R =>
  val idField = new LongField[R](this)
}
```